# VsCode dropping ssh connections frequently with remote server

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, connection, digital-ocean, remote-server

I'm facing a weird problem after connecting with the remote host using ssh in VSCode, the editor lost the connection after some seconds with the remote server (in this case a droplet in Digital Ocean). But when I open an ssh connection with the remote server using my local terminal instead of my local VSCode of my I do not see the same thing happen, in the terminal the connection keep alive for minutes, as expected.

Perhaps an ssh config on a remote server? I don't think so because using the terminal the problem doesn't occur.

[image: VSCode SSH REMOTE DROPPING CONN AFTER A SOME SECONDS]

So, what fix I can apply to my local VSCode configuration to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

It was keep happening with my M1 Macbook Pro. The solution was to uncheck  `useLocalServer` setting:  "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false.

This parameter is used to control whether to use a local server for managing SSH connections or not. When it is set to false, VS Code will use the built-in SSH client instead of a local server.

Here's how you can set this configuration:

Inside VS Code, click on the gear icon in the bottom left corner to open the Settings. In the Settings tab, you can either search for remote.SSH.useLocalServer or navigate to "Remote-SSH" settings.

Look for the setting `Remote.SSH: Use Local Server` and set it to false.

Alternatively, you can directly add this configuration to your settings.json file. Open the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P), type "`Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`", and add the following line:

```
"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/susanBuck/e2-fall21/issues/37 seems to address this issue. To summarise:

- set `Remote.SSH: Connect Timeout` in the VSC settings to `60`
- set your OpenSSH configuration to:

  ````
  HostName your.ip.address
  User root
  ServerAliveInterval 60
  ServerAliveCountMax 10```
  ````